# PyParsing not behaving as expected with nested grammar

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I have a question about nested grammar. How do you make pyparsing look for nested grammar constructs.

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, alphanums, Suppress, LineEnd, LineStart, nums, Or, Group, OneOrMore, Literal, CaselessLiteral, Combine, Optional

word = Word(alphanums+'_')

object_type = Suppress("object ")+word.setResultsName("object_type")+Suppress('{')+LineEnd()

point = Literal('.') 
e = CaselessLiteral('E') 
plusorminus = Literal('+') | Literal('-') 
number = Word(nums)  
integer = Combine( Optional(plusorminus) + number )
floatnumber = Combine( integer +
                       Optional( point + Optional(number) ) +
                       Optional( e + integer )
                     )

attribute = word.setResultsName("attribute") 
value = Or([floatnumber, word]).setResultsName("value")

attributes = Group(attribute+value+Suppress(";")+LineEnd()) 
namespace = Group(object_type+\ OneOrMore(attributes).setResultsName("attributes") + Suppress("}")) 
all = OneOrMore(namespace).setResultsName("namespaces")

result = all.parseString(glm)

for n in result.namespaces:
    print(n)
```

The following is an example of something I'd like to parse for example. The first namespace works as expected. The second however fails to parse. Can anyone explain what I am missing?

```
"""object object_type1{
attr1 0.0111;
name name_of_object_1;
}
object object_type1{
attr1 0.02;
name name_of_object_2;
    object object_type2{
    name name_of_object_3;
    }
}
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a recursive grammar, that is, one that has a term which itself is part of its own definition, you need to use pyparsing's `Forward` class. In your case, a `namespace` can contain either attributes or nested namespaces. To do this you first have to define a sort of placeholder for `namespace`:

```
namespace = Forward()
```

Then when it is time to define the contents (which include `namespace` as part of the definition), use the `<<=` operator instead of `=`:

```
namespace <<= Group(object_type + OneOrMore(attributes|namespace).setResultsName("attributes") + Suppress("}")) 
all = OneOrMore(namespace).setResultsName("namespaces")
```

Other than that, your parser should work just fine.

Just a couple of other tips:

- I recently added the `pprint()` method to simplify listing out the contents of a ParseResults object. Try `result.pprint()` instead of the for loop you are using now.
- You don't really need the newlines in your output, so replace all the `LineEnd()` terms with `LineEnd().suppress()` - this will neaten up your results a bit.
- I'm not sure the results names are really doing much for you in this case. But I find that using `expr("name")` is more readable than `expr.setResultsName("name")`. But either form will work okay.